# Windows 7 Logs in to "public" user

Tags: windows-7, login, user-accounts, public-folders

I have issues that sometimes when I log into windows (on a specific account) it shows public user (C:\Users\Public)'s desktop.

All of the users are in a domain. I tried deleting the user through account managment and deleting his folder from C:\Users but it didn't create another with the user's name on it - it just keeps logging in to public.

Did this happen to someone and knows what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this error quite a few times.  To fix this, it basically involves going into regedit and editing the user account in in.  Microsoft has detailed instructions at this link:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947242/en-us

Good Luck!